# How to change Gedit embeded terminal plugin colors?

Tags: unity, gedit

I am trying to use Gedit as an IDE for learning C. So far everything is working great but i have this problem: when using ls in its embedded terminal I am unable to see all the files and directories in my workspace directory (only shows .c files but not the .out and other directories), yet when i run terminal from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> all the files in the current directory show.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated. it seems to me that only the colored files aren't showing in the embedded terminal and i need them to show.

thank you!

Comment: Do they show with `ls -a`?

Comment: No, its the same with ls. However, they do show when using ctrl+alt+T. but hidden files is not the problem, not being able to show colored filed or directories is the problem. for example, when using ls on my home directory in embedded terminal, all what i see is the examples.desktop, but not all the other directories in there.

Comment: Oh, so it's when running `ls` from the terminal within `gedit`. Sorry, I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP is asking about a problem in Gedit embedded terminal plugin.

The only problem here is that the colour scheme is not good i.e., white prompt on light grey background makes it almost impossible to work. To change the colour scheme follow the next series of steps:

1. Open dconf-editor. If it is not installed, install it through the following command :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Once installed, execute it using the following command :

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
3. In the dconf editor window, go to `org->gnome->gedit->plugins->terminal`

   - deselect the use-theme-colors option.
   - clear palette settings
   - set foreground color: #FFFFFF
   - set background color: #000000

   [image]
4. Now restart the gedit program.

   [image]

Observe that a colour scheme of black prompt over light background is now active.

Comment: Nope I already did that and modified my embedded terminal to look like the other terminal. my issue is with ls. I can't post a screenshot yet but the whole matter is not being able to see all the files in the present directory. /bin/ls solved but i'm still trying to make it work with just ls.

Comment: use `dir` instead of `ls`

Comment: solved by clearing palette settings. see my edit

Comment: @user257841 check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Verify your .bashrc file, and see if it contains the following:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

If it doesn't have, add it. It must help to show dotfiles too.

Comment: it says alias ls ='ls --color=auto'
bash: alias: =:not found
bash: alias: 'ls --color': invalid alias name

Comment: Try removing the space between `ls` and `=` so it says `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Comment: Type `ls` at your home folder and see if the output is colored. If yes, try the same with option `-a`

Comment: Are you trying this commands within gedit terminal?

Comment: Ok, I did make an alias to ls but the problem still persists. Please note that this is only happening in the terminal that is embedded within gedit, everything works fine when using ctrl+alt+T

Comment: So try this `/bin/ls -a` within embedded console.

Comment: Nice! now I can see the files that I was unable to see but they're all in white? maybe if I do ls --color=auto this might work!

Comment: To see output colored type `/bin/ls -a --color=auto`

Comment: Sadly that did not work out but I am glad I can at least see my files and directories. Is there a way to do this without having to type /bin/ls? maybe if I make an alias to this for ls?