# Unable to change pallette settings in dconf gedit terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit

I followed the thread to fix the gedit white terminal issue.
[How to change Gedit embeded terminal plugin colors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433691/how-to-change-gedit-embeded-terminal-plugin-colors)

I'm stuck because I cannot change or delete the pallette setting in dconf.

This is the error I get:

```
"Erreur lors de la définition de la valeur : 0:expected value"
```

Is there a way to do it manually.
Any help?

```
gedit:
  Installé : 3.10.4-0ubuntu13
  Candidat : 3.10.4-0ubuntu13
 Table de version :
 *** 3.10.4-0ubuntu13 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thx

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `axi-cache policy gedit`

Comment: Excuse me, I have your question misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the behavior with

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal use-theme-colors true
  ```

  or

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal use-theme-colors false
  ```

  > If true, the theme color scheme used for text entry boxes will be used for the terminal, instead of colors provided by the user.

  or reset the behavior with

  ```
  gsettings reset org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal use-theme-colors
  ```
- An other example, to set the whole color palette use

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal palette "['#2E2E34343636', '#CCCC00000000', '#4E4E9A9A0606', '#C4C4A0A00000', '#34346565A4A4', '#757550507B7B', '#060698209A9A', '#D3D3D7D7CFCF', '#555557575353', '#EFEF29292929', '#8A8AE2E23434', '#FCFCE9E94F4F', '#72729F9FCFCF', '#ADAD7F7FA8A8', '#3434E2E2E2E2', '#EEEEEEEEECEC']"
  ```
- Or the `background-color`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal background-color "black"
  ```
- List all available keys with

  ```
  gsettings list-keys org.gnome.gedit.plugins.terminal
  ```

Comment: Sorry, changed my answer

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: still no results

Comment: What results do you expect?

Comment: I just want the terminal in gedit to be black (same as default).
Whatever the settings, it stays white.

Comment: the 'black' value doesn't change anything

Comment: And if you change the color direct in dconf-editor? If not, than it is a bug.

Comment: nope I tried everything