# I can not do that because org->gnome->gedit does not exist in dconfChange the background color of the embedded terminal in gedit

Tags: command-line, gnome, gedit

The embedded terminal in gedit has a white background and I would like to change it to black as it is in the teminal. I have tried this [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433691/how-to-change-gedit-embeded-terminal-plugin-colors) but, the gedit key org->gnome->gedit does not exist in dconf and find doesn't find anything for gedit in dconf. How else can I change the background color?

I can not do that because org->gnome->gedit does not exist in dconf.