# Change color of embedded terminal in gedit (Ubuntu 20)

Tags: command-line, gedit, colors

I can't change the color of the embedded terminal of Gedit in Ubuntu 20.
I've tried both this solution [Make gedit embedded terminal colours the same as the default terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67593/make-gedit-embedded-terminal-colours-the-same-as-the-default-terminal) and this one [Gedit embeded terminal color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796297/gedit-embeded-terminal-color) . With the second solution the embedded terminal plugin is corrupted and it's not more usable. I cannot do the first solution since I cannot install `dconf` and `gconf`

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 20 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question seems to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.

Comment: @guiverc the version is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Please correct your question, not everyone reads comments and currently your question implies you're using `gedit` as a *snap* running on GNOME or other desktop itself running on a *snap* because you used the *yy* format for releases (Ubuntu uses *yy* only for all *snap* based releases)